# CGminer multiple instances

Tags: cgminer, scrypt

I think I need to run multiple instances but they seem to effect each other.

- Device 0: 7970
- Device 1: 7970
- Device 2: 7950

I can get both 7970's into one instance with:

```
cgminer.exe --scrypt -I 13 --thread-concurrency 8192 -w 256 -d 0,1
```

but when I open another version of cgminer, in another folder, with another name, and a different batch file, like this:

```
cgminer2.exe --scrypt -I 20 --thread-concurrency 22400 -g 1 -w256
```

what happens is the core clocks of my first instance all change to match those of my second instance, despite not having set clocks in either batch file. (so my 7970 goes from 1050/1500 to 1125/1375) and worst of all obviously is I go from 720khs to 530 khs on my 7970's.

I can however go into the cgminer on the 7970's and tell it to change the clocks back to what I want, and it does, and all 3 cards run perfectly in two instances.

Is there any way to make it so the two instances don't see eachother? (`--remove-disabled` doesn't work)

---

EDIT:

It's been a while since I was mining, but IIRC it was just a matter of copying the cgminer folder and running the second copy. The problem I ran into above was because I didn't notice that the first miner created a mining.config file, which when I copied the folder, was running without my knowledge and applying its settings, even though I was changing them outside the mining.config file (I was using batch files for my configs.)

So it was really just a matter of targeting them with the -d parameter.

Comment: ahh i fixed it, there was a miner.config file in there that was kicking off on it's own. Now I successfully have two instances of cgminer and two instances of cgwatcher working fine :D

Comment: Could you edit your question and list how you solved this issue? Im looking to do the same